# R: filling matrix with values does not work

Tags: r

I have a data frame `vec` that I need to prepare for an `image.plot()` plot. The structure of `vec` is as follows:

```
> str(vec)
'data.frame':   31212 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ x : int  8 24 40 56 72 88 104 120 136 152 ...
 $ y : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ dx: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dy: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ d : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Note: the values in `$dx`, `$dy` and `$d` are not zero but only too small to be shown in this overview.

Background: the data is the output of a pixel tracking software. $x and $y are pixel coordinates while in $d are the displacement vector lengths (in pixels) of that pixel.

`image.plot()` expects as first and second argument the dimension of the matrix as ordered vectors, so I think `sort(unique(vec$x))` and `sort(unique(vec$y))` respectively should be good. So, I would like to end up with `image.plot(sort(unique(vec$x)),sort(unique(vec$y)), data)`

The third argument is the actual data. To build this I tried:

```
# spanning an empty matrix 
data = matrix(NA,length(unique(vec$x)),length(unique(vec$y)))
# filling the matrix
data[match(vec$x, sort(unique(vec$x))), match(vec$y, sort(unique(vec$y)))] = vec$d
```

But, unfortunately, this isn't working. It reports no errors but `data` contains no values! This works:

```
for(i in c(1:length(vec$x))) data[match(vec$x[i], sort(unique(vec$x))), match(vec$y[i], sort(unique(vec$y)))] = vec$d[i]
```

But is very slow.

a) is there a better way to build `data`?

b) is there a better way to deal with my problem, anyways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R allows indexing of a matrix by a two-column matrix, where the first column of the index is interpreted as the row index, and the second column as the column index. So create the indexes into data as a two-column matrix

```
idx = cbind(match(vec$x, sort(unique(vec$x))),
            match(vec$y, sort(unique(vec$y))))
```

and use that

```
data[idx] = vec$d
```

Comment: just to clarify, when the index `idx` is a matrix, rows in the matrix are interpreted as locations in the matrix being assigned to.  When you use two index variables (i.e. `data[a,b] <- x`),   `x` is assigned to the intersection of rows specified by `a` and columns specifiied by `b`.

Comment: @Jthorpe yes, that's right. For `m = matrix(0, 5, 5)`, compare `m[cbind(c(1, 3), c(2, 4))] = 1` and `m[c(1, 3), c(2, 4)]`; you're interested in the former.

Comment: @Martin Morgan: that's working fantastically well! Thank you very much. And it's so fast!!!